# Call a method when Java application is force closed

Tags: java

I want to call a method when I terminating my Java application forcefully. I need to release resource I used in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you mean by "forcefully", but I expect you want to add a Shutdown hook.

Shutdown hooks are small threads which are called whenever Java attempts to shut down. You can add one using the Runtime API, like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread hook)
```

Of course, if you *really* force a shutdown (by turning the machine off, or running kill -9 on it,) the operating system will shut down Java without giving it a chance to clean up anything. In that case, you won't be able to do anything about it.

Comment: What about System.exit()? I guess shutdownhook will not get called in this scenario also.

Comment: Yes, they are called with System.exit(). It's only if the OS forces the shutdown rather than Java that you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This'll be what you want:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { 
        // release your resource
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Shutdownhook: Here is example:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime ().addShutdownHook ( 
new Thread () {   
          @Override    
         public void run () {    
             System.out.println ( "Shutdown hook" );  

        }      
   } );
```